# Design time ItemsSource on ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I'm trying to design the `DataTemplate` for my `ItemsControl` and I need some mock data to populate the template. I read using `d:DataContext` is enough so that I don't have to create a mock class. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The instance you have to use with d:DataContext must be declared in the XAML, with a `StaticResource` for example.

Here is how you could do it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:MyViewModel x:Key="mockViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl d:DataContext="{StaticResource mockViewModel}" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The class I used as data context is defined as follows:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class Item
    {
        public Item(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public List<Item> Items
        {
            get 
            {
                return new List<Item>() { new Item("Thing 1"), new Item("Thing 2") };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can also set the data context on the `UserControl` or on your Window.

Here's the result:
[image]

Comment: I read that loading it as a resource will make the application also load it on run-time. I'm using `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=mocks:MyViewModelMock, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}` but it doesn't work

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco Using d:DesignInstance works too. 
Try to restart VS and rebuild your solution. The Designer is sometimes a little lazy with updating...